# Parse Cloud code written in ES6?

Tags: parse-platform

Can Parse Cloud code be written in ES6? Currently, I'm creating one of my cloud files like this:

```
var Job = Parse.Object.extend("Job");
Parse.Cloud.Define("createJob", function(request, response) {
  var job = new Job();
  job.set("name", request.params.name);
  job.save();
  response.success();
});
```

This was a shortened version of what it actually is. Ideally I would like to create a class for it like this:

```
class Job extends Parse.Object {
  var name;
  var descriptionText;
  constructor(name, descriptionText) {
    this.name = name;
    this.descriptionText = descriptionText;
  }
}

Parse.Cloud.Define("createJob", function(request, response) {
  var job = new Job(request.params.name, request.params.descriptionText);
  job.save();
});
```

However, this doesn't work. Am I missing something or is this simply not possible? I'm an iOS developer looking to create some better JavaScript cloud code.

Comment: Parse says: "If you’re already using ES6 in your codebase, good news! From version 1.6.0 onwards, the JavaScript SDK is compatible with ES6 classes" (see https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-parse-object). So, yes, this should be possible, as long as you are using JS SDK >= 1.6.0 (at your command prompt, run `parse jssdk 1.6.14`). What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write Parse Cloud code correct? I believe that the docs that [Lane Rettig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2397068/lane-rettig) referenced are talking about the Parse Javascript SDK which does support some ES6 features such as classes. To my knowledge, Parse Cloud Code does not support ES6 or classes. I don't believe that they will support ES6 since Parse is shutting down in less than a year. It does look like there is community support to make the open source Parse Server that Parse has released ES6 compatible. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/194

So, I guess you are stuck doing it the old way, creating a function that does all that for you or writing classes the old ES5 way with a function and prototype until you switch to parse-server and it supports ES6.